# Transfer comments from one domain to another

Tags: comments, multisite

We have two domains with separate WP installs, it's not a multisite network.  We would like to send or transfer comments from domain A to domain B so domain B handles all moderation because we'd like to minimize maintenance as much as possible and domain B is the main site that receives the most traffic within our network.

Is it possible to send or transfer comments to the admin backend for moderation between two domains?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should explain better the motivation. What do you mean in "minimize maintenance"? comments still needs to be approved no matter where are they posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the comments on site A and place a note like "If you have a remark, please voice your opinion on our main site B". It is not very nice but not unheard of.